# A profile center link is missing from this email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In Marketing Cloud, I am facing error message : "A profile center link is missing from this email. For template based email, please contact our customer service."

[image]

What should I do ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add the required [**Personalization Strings**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/) to your email HTML as outlined in the error message:

**Subscription Center**: `%%subscription_center_url%%`

**Profile Center**: `%%profile_center_url%%`

**One-click Unsubscribe**: `%%unsub_center_url%%`

**Sender address**: `%%member_busname%%`
`%%member_addr%%`
`%%member_city%%`
`%%member_state%%`
`%%member_postalcode%%`
`%%member_country%%`

Further reference:

- [The AMPscript Guide - Personalization Strings Overview](https://ampscript.guide/personalization-strings-overview/)

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to this, we found we were getting click throughs using the scripting hack from Adam so changed to the  solution from Data_Kid.

This sometimes displayed the ridiculously long link for (at least) Windows users on Outlook 16 so am now using:-

```
<div style="display:none"><a href="%%profile_center_url%%">.</a></div>
```

which displays a fullstop at worst.

Answer (score 2):

There's one circumstance under which Adam's answer is not correct - if you are using your own CRM/website for unsubscribes.  If so, talk to your AE or support to have that warning disabled on your account.

Comment: There's also a scripting hack to bypass it -- `%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%%%%profile_center_url%%%%[endif]%%`

Comment: You could also do <div style="display:none"> %%profile_center_url%% </div>