# Enabling Custom Profile Center

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have built custom profile center but can't figure out how to over ride the default one. When I try to render the email it throws an error saying I do not have a profile center link. Would appreciate guidance on this.

Comment: could it be related to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145196/a-profile-center-link-is-missing-from-this-email ?

Comment: Not directly. Those strings will give the default variables. I am looking for a way to insert my custom links into them. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the default footer links to whatever you want in the [**Administration section**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/administration/headersandfooters/).

If you're using straight HTML for your emails, I'd suggest using the [**MicrositeURL()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/MicrositeURL.htm) or [**CloudpagesURL()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) function to link to your profile center pages.

Both URLs will carry the subscriber context to your pages automatically.

You can pass additional attributes in both, but you can only [**retrieve the values with AMPScript**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/a-case-for-the-micrositeurl-function/).