# Custom footer problems

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have some issues with a custom html footer in Marketing Cloud. I would like to setup the accounts settings (custom footer).
I have my html code, but for some reason i got the following error message the picture below.[image: error image]

Here you have my html code. I already check the all the mandatory items, but I couldn't find a reason for that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Footer</title>
<div style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" class="footer">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background:#fff;">

<!-- FOOTER CONTENT -->
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="background:#F3F3F3;" width="100%">
    <table class="container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600"><table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="background:#F3F3F3;" width="100%">
        <table class="container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
        <td align="center" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 15px; color: #29395f; padding:9px 0px 25px 0px;">
        Fique por dentro das novidades <b>em nossas redes:</b> <tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="background:#F3F3F3;" width="100%">
<table class="container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
<tr>

<a href="insert a link here"
              ><img
                src="https://mcusercontent.com/176de8164aa4fb0be0e9f8b5a/images/3bdfed99-8439-1387-76c9-6b2fb4658be6.png"
                nosend="1"
                border="0"
                width="24"
                height="24"
                alt="Whatsapp"/></a
            >&nbsp&nbsp
            <a href="insert a facebook link here"
              ><img
                src="https://mcusercontent.com/dffedd34e0eff3c56daec7d25/images/f9c323a9-cb5d-9079-7010-d31a4f381bf4.png"
                nosend="1"
                border="0"
                width="24"
                height="24"
                alt="Facebook"/></a
            >&nbsp&nbsp
            <a href="insert a instagram link here"
              ><img
                src="https://mcusercontent.com/176de8164aa4fb0be0e9f8b5a/images/d5111a55-a7d8-5041-71e2-e959835c083f.png"
                nosend="1"
                border="0"
                width="24"
                height="24"
                alt="Instagram"/></a
            >&nbsp&nbsp
            <a href="insert a linkedin link here"
              ><img
                src="https://mcusercontent.com/dffedd34e0eff3c56daec7d25/images/5caf56dc-7028-d586-5289-6303edb92da7.png"
                nosend="1"
                border="0"
                width="24"
                height="24"
                alt="Youtube"/></a
            >&nbsp&nbsp
            <a
              href="insert a youtube link here"
              ><img
                src="https://mcusercontent.com/176de8164aa4fb0be0e9f8b5a/images/13dc6034-d3f7-0fef-d1a8-aeba6d3e02a2.png"
                nosend="1"
                border="0"
                width="24"
                height="24"
                alt="Linkedin"/></a
            >
          </td>
        </tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="background:#F3F3F3;" width="100%">
<table class="container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
<tr>
<td align="left" style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #fe0064; padding: 0px 30px 13px 30px;">
<b>Company Name</b></tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #29395f; line-height: 1.8; padding:0px 30px 13px 30px;">
Fale conosco por <b>Whatsapp: (xx) xxxx-xxxx</b> | Seg. a Sex. - 7h às 19h, exceto feriados <br>
SAC: xxxx xxx xxxx / PPD: xxxx xxx xxxx | Atendimento todos os dias, 24 horas por dia.<br>
Ouvidoria: PPD: xxxx xxx xxxx / 0800 720 4366 | Seg. a Sex. - 8h às 22h e aos sábados das 9h às 14h, exceto feriados. </tr><br>

<tr>
<td align="left" style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #fe0064; padding:0px 30px 13px 30px;">
<b>Segurança</b></tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #29395f; line-height: 1.8; padding:0px 30px 13px 30px;">
Veja 3 passos para identificar uma <b>comunicação segura</b> da Sim: <br>
<b>1- Confira o remetente</b><br>
As comunicações da Company Name são enviadas por <b>@email.com</b> e/ou <b>@email.com</b><br>
<b>2- A comunicação possui link?</b><br>
Passe o mouse sobre o endereço do link e verifique a autenticidade. Ele deve começar com <b>website</b> <br>
<b>3- Não informe dados sigilosos</b><br>
Desconfie de e-mails ou SMS solicitando informações pessoais ou senhas.<br></tr>

<tr>
<td style="padding: 0px; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><div style="text-align: center;">
 <hr style="width: 20%; border:0.2px solid #fe0064;"></tr>
 
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="background:#F3F3F3;" width="100%">
<table class="container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #29395f; padding:15px 30px 0px 30px;">
A Company Name é uma plataforma digital que faz parte do Grupo...<br>
A avaliação definitiva do seu crédito acontecerá no momento que completar sua proposta em nosso site.<br>
Caso não queira receber mais nossos e-mails, 
<a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" alias="Unsubscribe" target="_blank" style="font-size:9px; color: #fe0064; text-decoration: none; font-weight:normal;">clique aqui.</a></span>
<br><br>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="background:#F3F3F3;" width="100%">
        <table class="container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 9px; color: #29395f; padding:0px 0px 25px 0px;">
                This email was sent by<br> 
                <span>%%Member_Busname%%<br>
                <span>%%Member_Addr%%, %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%% %%Member_Country%%</span>
                <br>
                <br>
                <a href="http://www.exacttarget.com/privacy-policy" alias="Privacy Policy" target="_blank" style="font-size:9px; color: #29395f; text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile" target="_blank" style="font-size:9px; color: #29395f; text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;">Update Profile</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="%%subscription_center_url%%" alias="Manage Subscriptions" target="_blank" style="font-size:9px; color: #29395f; text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;">Manage Subscriptions</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" alias="Unsubscribe" target="_blank" style="font-size:9px; color: #29395f; text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;">Unsubscribe</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A profile center link is missing from this email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145196/a-profile-center-link-is-missing-from-this-email)

Comment: @zuzannamj - I admit the question is the same, but the thread actually doesn’t contain an answer mentioning disabling of CAN-SPAM Check becoming self-service

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by your footer failing the CAN-SPAM check. You can disable the criteria causing it to fail, in Marketing Cloud Setup. You need to find: **Setup > Email Settings > Email Optional Features**

Here you will be able to toggle these three settings into the off-position:

1. Profile Link Check
2. Physical Address Check
3. Unsubscribe Link Check

Once disabled, your email should be validated again, without throwing the same error

Comment: Following the directions in the error message - be sure that the TEXT version of your email also has the personalization strings removed (if you go this route). I've lost count to the number of times a change was applied to the HTML version, but the error still appearing b/c a client didn't also go in to the TEXT version to adjust.